# c++ argv[1] terminate the program with return value 9009

Tags: c++

I have a small code to look whats the `argv`'s

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    cout << "===================" << endl;
    cout << "argc: " << argc << endl << endl;
    cout << "argv[0]: " << argv[0] << endl << endl;
    cout << "argv[1]: " << argv[1] << endl << endl;
    //cout << "argv[2]: " << argv[2] << endl << endl; //Program crash
    cout << "===================" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I start the program with no parameters:

`argc` is 1
`argv[0]` is the execution path
`argv[1]` should be out of range and the program should crash, but the program terminates like I write `return`. If I check the errorlevel it is 9009
If I try to access `argv[2]` the program crashs as expected

(When I start the program with one parameter everything works fine)

Why it doesn't crash like `argv[2]` when I access `argv[1]`?
And for what stand errorlevel 9009?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing an array out of bounds gives no error, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why)

Comment: C++ doesn't have bounds-checking. Indexing out of bounds leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Any speculation about behavior is useless.

Comment: Which compiler are you using ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - `argv[argc]` is always null, and is not out of bounds for the array.

Comment: Also note that `argv[argc]` (which will be `argv[1]` in your case) is *always* a null pointer. So technically it's not really out of bounds (as noted by @StoryTeller)

Comment: @rak007 g++ compiler.

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude yes I know that but why it's doesn't crash like argv[2].

Comment: @All Thanks for your answers, and for what stand 9009 or is this defined on the OS?

Comment: @Morchul Because *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so 9009 stand for undefined behavior?

Comment: @Morchul No, undefined behavior could lead to *anything* happening, from conjuring [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) to seemingly working or to your program exiting with an error code being *anything* (which include the value `9009`.

Comment: @Morchul- Undefined behavior is formal term that means you can't use the language spec to explain what happens. Your program is essentially illegal, and you shouldn't complain if it behaves weird. 9009 probably stands for something, but it's probably not "you wrote bad C++".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't crash because `argv` is defined as a null terminated array. The last element is `argv[argc]`, that always holds a null pointer. You aren't accessing out of bounds for the array.

But...

You pass a null pointer value to `std::ostream`'s `operator<<` for c-strings. That is undefined in and of itself, so your program isn't exactly well behaved in this case either.

Answer (score 3):

> ... and the program should crash.

No, no, no!

The whole point of undefined behaviour is that it's, well, *undefined.*

Literally *anything* is allowed to happen when you dereference a null pointer (which `argv[argc]` is required to be, and `ostream::operator<<` will try to dereference it) including, and this is the most insidious aspect of UB, it working as expected sometimes, or it failing with a frankly bizarre return code :-)

But, bottom line, if you break the contract with the standard, all bets are off. Don't do it.

Comment: @Morchul: It may or it may not. It's totally up to the implementation what it returns under UB conditions.